# Mongoose Server selection error [ECONNREFUSED]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I started a new ExpressJS app and I am having trouble getting connected to my localhost MongoDB on Windows OS.I have read through countless forums and tried everything to get mongod and the mongodb-community server started, but nothing has worked. The error I am getting is below:

> connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\User\Desktop\harta2\no
> at C:\Users\User\Desktop\harta2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:340:
> at C:\Users\User\Desktop\harta2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promi
> at new Promise ()
> at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\User\Desktop\harta2\node_modules\mongoos
> at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\User\Desktop\harta2\node_modul
> at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\User\Desktop\harta2\node_modules\mongoose
> at Object. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\harta2\server.js:5:10)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149
> reason: TopologyDescription {
> type: 'Unknown',
> servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
> stale: false,
> compatible: true,
> heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
> localThresholdMS: 15,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
> }
> }
> node:internal/process/promises:265
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

Mongoose connection code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wageTeam',{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () =>{
    console.log("Database connected");
});

const app = express();
```

Used this to start the server:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\mongodb\bin"
start mongod.exe
timeout 4
start mongo.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

first make sure that mongo service is exist and running because from what I see it is not working

[image: like this]

if it is not exist reinstall MongoDB service.

Comment: The mongo service exists and i checked if it was running every time i opened the project

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my node version from v18 to v16.15.0
and it works very fine in my system